# C++: Read string from cin stream and store values separated by space

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, stream, cin

Actually I came up with (temporary) solution but I still think it could've been done more efficient, but how? Im not quite familiar with streams (still a C++ beginner). My point is to read line from `std::cin` stream using `std::getline()` (I assumed that it can be only read as string) so I tried to set some `std::string::const_iterator` and iterate over each char my string contains using `' '` as a delimiter to distinguish different words (values) in my string. I will read only two integers separated by single space.

Example:

> Input:
>
> 2 (the number of cases)
>
> 10 20
>
> 30 40

Result:

Store 10 in variable `A`, 20 in variable `B`, 30 in variable `C`... etcetera.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    bool next;
    unsigned short int cases;
    long long m, n;
    std::vector<long long> vcases;
    std::string m_n_store;
    std::string m_n_read;
    std::cin >> cases;
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < cases; ++i)
    {
        next = false;
        std::getline(std::cin, m_n_read);
        for (std::string::const_iterator it = m_n_read.begin(); it != m_n_read.end(); ++it)
        {
            if (*it == ' ')
            {
                next = true;
                std::istringstream iss(m_n_store);
                iss >> m;
                vcases.push_back(m);
                m_n_store.erase();
            }
            if (!next) m_n_store.push_back(*it);
            else if (*it != ' ') m_n_store.push_back(*it);
            if (it == (m_n_read.end() - 1))
            {
                std::istringstream iss(m_n_store);
                iss >> n;
                vcases.push_back(n);
                m_n_store.erase();
            };
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < vcases.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << vcases[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
size_t pos = 0;
while ((pos = m_n_read.find(" ")) != std::string::npos) {
    std::istringstream iss(m_n_read.substr(0, pos));
    iss >> m;
    vcases.push_back(m);
    m_n_read.erase(0, pos + 1);
} 
if (m_n_read.size() > 0)
{
    std::istringstream iss(m_n_read);
    iss >> m;
    vcases.push_back(m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ streams, by default, delimit input operations by whitespace. There's no need to iterate through a string and break it by the space character. You can use `std::istream_iterator` and the range constructor of the vector instead:

```c++
std::vector<long long> mcases{std::istream_iterator<long long>{std::cin}, {}};
```